# What is difference between non-clustered index and non-clustered ColumnStore index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I try both indexes in SQL Server 2012 but confused with syntax, is there any difference between both type of index or both are same? 
If same than why they create new keyword columnstore in sql.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: One is stored by row, the other by column.  See:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, please clear one more thing. If clustered and non-clustered both saving data row wise than how query response quickly on adding non-clustered index.

Comment: They are totally different. Non clustered indexes are stored as a B tree that allows seeking on the key. Non clustered column store indexes don't have a key and are a separate compressed column oriented storage for the columns contained in the index. This is to optimise queries that perform full scans of few columns.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the simplified picture below, both indexes are organized as columns but NCCI is created on an existing rowstore table as shown on the right side in the picture below while a table with CCI does not have a rowstore table. Both tables can have one or more btree nonclustered indexes.

[image]

Other than this, the physical structures on how data is stored in delta and compressed rowgroups [image]are identical and both kinds of indexes have same performance optimizations including batchmode operators. However, there some  key differences between these and the table below lists the main differences.

Source :- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/07/18/columnstore-index-differences-between-clusterednonclustered-columnstore-index/

Comment: The question is asking for difference between NCI and NCCI. Not NCCI and CCI.

Comment: Agree with sir @MartinSmith. Kindly share your thoughts on NCCI vs NCI